# I have XML trained file of smiley want to run this XML using SVM and predict the result it by giving image

Tags: opencv, svm

I have XML trained file for smiley detection. I want to use this XML file to predict the results using SVM for a given test image.

I am following the tutorial given at the following link:

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/10/histogram-oriented-gradients-object-detection/

How can I load the XML file for SVM?

Answer (score 0):

```
CvSVM *SVM = new CvSVM;
SVM->load("SVM.xml");
```